# Does the Cholesky decomposition of a covariance matrix lead to a lower triangular matrix with positive diagonals?

Tags: covariance-matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, cholesky-decomposition

We know that an $N\times N$ covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is symmetric positive definite, and can be factorized using Cholesky decomposition as follows
\begin{equation}
\Sigma=LL'
\end{equation}
where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix. Since $\Sigma$ is positive definite that would imply the diagonal elements of $L$ are non-zero and correspond to the eigenvalues of matrix $L$. My questions are as follows:

1. Are said eigenvalues all positive? Or can no conclusions be made about the eigenvalues based on the info provided?
2. If the above holds true, suppose an $N\times p$ matrix $X$ generated according to $N(0,I_{p\times p})$ and is then set as fixed. Further, suppose an $N\times 1$ vector $\epsilon$ follows $\epsilon \sim N(0,I_{N\times N})$. If the above statement is true, would the below conclusion be correct?

\begin{equation}
\lVert X'\epsilon\rVert_{\infty}\leq \lVert X'L\epsilon\rVert_{\infty}
\end{equation}

Comment: Due to the shape constraint (triangular) on a Cholesky factor, $L$ doesn't fit the common definitions of positive definite which require *symmetry*. However, if $\Sigma$ is symmetric positive definite, then the diagonal elements of $L$ are all positive -- and I think that's what you're asking about in (1). // You refer to $N$ and $n$. Is it true that $N=n$?

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you for very valid observations. I have edited the question to reflect the issues you raised, Yes $N=n$!